# Bad Request at respond node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:264:15

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am very dummy on ElasticSearch and I have little experience with NodeJs. I have created few cruds using NodeJs + MongoDb. I have to change from MongoDb to ElasticSearch (this is mandatory). Please, I don't want to compare MOngoDb with ElasticSearch so don't try that.

I am following the example found here

```
https://blog.raananweber.com/2015/11/24/simple-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-and-node-js/
```

I have started succesfully ElasticSearch. I can see:

```
nodejs express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master # curl --noproxy -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/?pretty'
{
  "name" : "-em7X-s",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "cqJUaPcFREe4wX_YyYWoFg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.2.1",
    "build_hash" : "db0d481",
    "build_date" : "2017-02-09T22:05:32.386Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

However, when I try to start the sample above or access I get the error bellow respectvely:

```
/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master $ npm start

> autocompleter@0.0.0 start /home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master
> node ./bin/www

Elasticsearch INFO: 2017-02-16T20:00:48Z
  Adding connection to http://localhost:9200/

Unhandled rejection Error: Bad Request
    at respond (/home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:264:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:223:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:155:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
Unhandled rejection Error: [illegal_argument_exception] request [/randomindex/_suggest] contains unrecognized parameter: [type]
    at respond (/home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:264:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:223:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:155:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
Unhandled rejection Error: [illegal_argument_exception] request [/randomindex/_suggest] contains unrecognized parameter: [type]
    at respond (/home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:264:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:223:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:155:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/home/demetrio/dev/samples/express.js-elasticsearch-autocomplete-demo-master/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

I am very confused what to check. Any suggestion will be appreciated. My final target is to understand how to connect to ElasticSearch from NodeJs application

Comment: **DemeCarvO** Did you figure out what the issue was ?

Comment: Well, nevermind, there were some breaking changes with elastic 5.2

Comment: same issue for me. Please let me know if you figure out the issue